# angular2 services returns undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I cannot get the reason why one of my services always returns `undefined` however network tab in developer mode shows me that data has been received.

Could somebody help me to figure out where my mistake is?

My component looks next way:

```
export interface Sponsors {
      id;
      sponsorCode;
      sponsorName;
      active;
      clientId;
      countryId;
      cloudRegionId;
    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-sponsors',
      templateUrl: './sponsors.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./sponsors.component.css'],
    })

    export class SponsorsComponent implements OnInit {

      id: any;     
      sponsors: Sponsors[];
      applications: Applications[];

      constructor(private appService: AppServices,
                  private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.id = route.snapshot.url[1].path;
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getSponsors();
        this.getApps();
      }

      getSponsors () {
        this.appService.getSponsorsByClient(this.id).then(
          response => {
            this.sponsors = response;
            console.log(this.sponsors) //returns undefined
        });
      }

      getApps(){
        this.appService.getApplications()
          .then(applications => {
            this.applications = applications;
            console.log(this.applications) // returns data
          });
      }
```

This is my services:

```
getSponsorsByClient(id: any): Promise<Sponsors[]> {
    const url = `${this.api}/clients/${id}/sponsors`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Sponsors[])
  }

getApplications(): Promise<Applications[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.api + "/applications")
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Applications[])
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.then(response => response.json().data as Sponsors[])` this does have `.data`, while another method doesn't. Can this be the reason?

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin so silly, that was my problem. Thanks for notice!

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
getApplications(): Promise<Applications[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.api + "/applications")
               .map(response => response.json() as Applications[])
               .toPromise();
}
```