# Angular 2 Service Observable returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I recently started playing around with Angular and trying to achieve the simple task of getting some resources from a DB, sorting them and displaying them.

However the component receives undefined and can not sort.

I have looked at the following threads

[angular2 observable, getting undefined in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172955/angular2-observable-getting-undefined-in-component)

[angular2 services returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961973/angular2-services-returns-undefined)

[angular2 observable, getting undefined in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172955/angular2-observable-getting-undefined-in-component)

I started off Google's tutorial at [angular.io](http://angular.io) and expanded/modified the code according to my needs

and tried the following:

Service:

```
import { Album } from './album'; 
import { ALBUMS } from './mock-albums';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AlbumService {

  private albumURL = '/api/albums';

  constructor (private http: Http) { }

  getAlbums(): Promise<Album[]> {

    return this.http.get(this.albumURL)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {response.json().data as Album[]; 
                   console.log(response)})
            .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Also tried the following 3 inside the body of getAlbums() as suggested by other threads

```
  return this.http.get(this.albumURL)
          .map(response => response.json().data as Album[])
          .toPromise();

   return this.http.get(this.albumURL)
        .map(response => {response.json().data as Album[]) 

  return this.http.get(this.albumURL)
        .map(response => { return response.json().data as Album[]})
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Album } from './album';
import { AlbumService } from './album.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'album-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'dashboard.component.css' ]
 })  

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

 albums: Album[] = [];

 constructor(private albumService: AlbumService) { };

 ngOnInit(): void {

   this.albumService.getAlbums()
      .then(result => this.albums = result.sort((function(a,b){
         return (a.artist > b.artist) ? 1 : ((b.artist > a.artist) ? -1 : 0);
       }))) 
 }

 .... the rest of the class continues
```

Also tried the following in the component:

```
this.albumService.getAlbums()
   .subscribe(result => this.albums = result.sort((function(a,b){
    return (a.artist > b.artist) ? 1 : ((b.artist > a.artist) ? -1 : 0);
})))
```

I get the following error and have concluded that for some reason the service returns before the Promise resolves but I might be wrong

Can not read property sort of undefined

[image]

An important thing to note is that console.log(response) on the service code above, prints out the correct response from the server. So the data does reach the correct angular service but something happens between the service and component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove casting inside the service, when it fails you will not be able to access

```
return this.http.get(this.albumURL)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {response.json(); 
                   console.log(response)})
            .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: @Sajaeetharan Thank you! I couldn't get your exact response to work yet, but it works if I remove the casting from the .map case. 
Could you possibly give a little bit more detail on why casting breaks this? Does it return an empty instance when it fails or something ?